# Are there any project methodologies for UI Design?

Tags: gui-design, methodology, project, management

For my graduation assignment I'm going to design a completely new UI for my company's software. One of the requirements my university imposes is that the entire process be based on a project management methodology. Which one is doesn't matter, as long as there's some proper structure behind it.
I've googled around a bit but every one I can find (like SCRUM, Prince2, UCD) feature for a large part the actual development of the UI, which in my case is unnecessary.

So, are there any methodologies out there that focus solely on the design of interfaces? (Ideally Garrett's Planes of UX shape into project management)

Comment: Try looking into [Lean UX](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/07/lean-ux-getting-out-of-the-deliverables-business/). While not an officially documented methodology (as far as I have found anyway) it's probably more or less what you're looking for.

Comment: I doubt that there are any. Most project management systems are designed for any project to fit into them. If you're trying to develop a piece of software you'd want to use a consistent methodology across back end and front end

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few links that might help with your research ...

http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/pdfs/Forrester_Best_Prac_In_User_Exp.pdf

http://www.useit.com/alertbox/user-research-methods.html

http://www.useit.com/alertbox/agile-user-experience.html

http://www.thinkingandmaking.com/view/agile-ux-six

Hope that helps.  Have a great day.